# Designing subclasses with functions that return sibling subclass objects

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, forward-declaration

I'm working on a set of subclasses (e.g. `SprocketTypeA`, `SprocketTypeB`, and `SprocketTypeC`) to a base class (e.g. `Sprocket`). The subclasses are different ways to describe a `Sprocket` in the same way that a measurement can be described in different units or different coordinate frames. In other words, a particular instance of `SprocketTypeA` can be equivalently expressed as a `SprocketTypeB` or `SprocketTypeC` object under particular transformations.

As a result, it would be natural for each subclass to have a `toSprocketTypeX()` function for each of the other types of `Sprocket` objects. E.g. `SprocketTypeA sta; SprocketTypeB stb = sta.toSprocketTypeB();`.

The problem seems to be that each type of `Sprocket` must know about the constructors for all other types of `Sprocket` objects before compiling, but all of those types of `Sprocket` must know about the constructors for all other types of `Sprocket`, and so on.

Here is some example skeleton code of the situation. Notice that the forward declarations listed don't solve the problem, because the `toSprocketTypeX()` functions must construct a `SprocketTypeX` object in their implementations.

`Sprocket` base class

```
#ifndef SPROCKET_HPP
#define SPROCKET_HPP

class Sprocket {
public:
  ...
private:
  ...
};

#endif
```

`SprocketTypeA` (`Sprocket` subclass)

```
#ifndef SPROCKETTYPEA_HPP
#define SPROCKETTYPEA_HPP

#include <Sprocket.hpp>
#include <SprocketTypeB.hpp>
#include <SprocketTypeC.hpp>

class SprocketTypeB;
class SprocketTypeC;
class SprocketTypeA: public Sprocket {
public:
  ...
  SprocketTypeB toSprocketTypeB() const;
  SprocketTypeC toSprocketTypeC() const;
};

#endif
```

`SprocketTypeB` (`Sprocket` subclass)

```
#ifndef SPROCKETTYPEB_HPP
#define SPROCKETTYPEB_HPP

#include <Sprocket.hpp>
#include <SprocketTypeA.hpp>
#include <SprocketTypeC.hpp>

class SprocketTypeA;
class SprocketTypeC;
class SprocketTypeB: public Sprocket {
public:
  ...
  SprocketTypeA toSprocketTypeA() const;
  SprocketTypeC toSprocketTypeC() const;
};

#endif
```

`SprocketTypeC` (`Sprocket` subclass)

```
#ifndef SPROCKETTYPEC_HPP
#define SPROCKETTYPEC_HPP

#include <Sprocket.hpp>
#include <SprocketTypeA.hpp>
#include <SprocketTypeB.hpp>

class SprocketTypeA;
class SprocketTypeB;
class SprocketTypeC: public Sprocket {
public:
  ...
  SprocketTypeA toSprocketTypeA() const;
  SprocketTypeB toSprocketTypeB() const;
};

#endif
```

One possible solution would be to return a `Sprocket` pointer (e.g. `Sprocket* toSprocketTypeX()`), but that's a bit too much of a kludge for me. I'm open to solutions to this issue or another design that supports the `toSprocketTypeX()` pattern.

Comment: Forward declaring `A` is sufficient for method declarations with return type `A`, unless you define the methods in the `.h` as well

Comment: It won't compile with only the forward declarations. In the .cpp implementations of the toSprocketTypeX() functions, constructors of the incomplete types must be called. The error is "invalid use of incomplete type"

Comment: Well, of course in your .cpp files you need to `#include` the headers. But the headers only need fwd declarations. And I'm glad you added header guards.

Comment: Yes, in each .cpp file I include the corresponding header, e.g. `#include <SprocketTypeA.hpp>` in SprocketTypeA.cpp.

Comment: Thanks for your help, turns out one of the subclass header files was missing the include lines for the other Sprocket subclass types >.<